# Golang / Gin Form Field Validation with ShouldBindWith

Tags: go

I am passing HTML form to data to a controller in Go. I am working off [boilerplate](https://github.com/Massad/gin-boilerplate/blob/master/README.md) to teach myself Go, and it includes form validation. The relevant statement, already changed somewhat from its original appearance in the boilerplate, is below:

```
if err := c.ShouldBindWith(&signinForm, binding.Form); err != nil {
      log.Println("err: ",err)
      c.JSON(406, gin.H{"message": "Invalid signin form", "form": signinForm})
      c.Abort()
      return
  }
```

The `err` logs as `Key: 'SigninForm.Email' Error:Field validation for 'Email' failed on the 'email' tag`.

In particular, I don't really know what `c.ShouldBindWith(&signinForm, binding.Form)` does (it was suggested by someone else in regards to my previous issue with `signinForm` being empty, which it solved).

How do I properly validate the form fields so that `err == nil`?

Comment: If you want `err == nil` to be true just provide a valid email so that validation doesn't fail.

Comment: It still fails when I provide a valid email. I don't think this statement is actually attempting to validate anything, which is what confuses me.

Comment: The error says "... Field validation ..." so i'm pretty certain that it's attempting validation. Gin's binding, as far as I understand, decodes the context request's body into the provided object and at the same time validates the content of the body based on the object's field tag directives. E.g `EmailField string \`binding:"email,required"\``.

Comment: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#model-binding-and-validation states that it's using https://github.com/go-playground/validator to validate your objects, and if you look here https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/e3037695c7ae7262d462bbd8698f621ca768d128/errors.go#L13 you can see exactly where from the message you're getting originates.

Comment: Ah yes, I got it! Thank you. If you want to post that last comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to validate forms using `shouldBind`

```
bindError := c.ShouldBind(&signinForm, binding.Form)

if bindError != nil {
  log.Println("err: ",err)
  c.JSON(406, gin.H{"message": "Invalid signin form", "form": signinForm})
  return
}
```